# CSS issues in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm having the weirdest most annoying issue with my web page. It's located at [2012sbc.com/demo][1]. If you click on the link for Promotional Material, then click on one of the downloads, then refresh the Promotional Materials page, it's using the a:visited, a:hover, and a:active properties from an entirely different div, the navigation.

I tried to set a whole new div for just the links on the page, and then those properties mess with my navigation!! I can't just like, set a class, then set another one, they interact with each other and I have no idea why. And of course, it's only happening in `IE7`.

Can someone check it out and tell me what I did wrong? I'm at a complete loss!!

edit: 
Screenshot located: https://trigger.lwcdirect.com/LWC_00486/uploadImages/2012sbc/screenshot.gif

And I personally don't care about IE7, but that's what our client uses and so I have to make it work.

2nd edit:
None of these things are helping, does anyone else have any suggestions?

Comment: It's time that you just forget that god forsaken browser.

Comment: What does it look like, and what do you expect it to look like? Showing screenshots and/or CSS would be helpful.

Comment: How are you checking the page? If you're using IE9 and telling it to render it as IE7 the page won't load the same way as it would do in a native IE7 install. And, while @xFortyFourx is right and you technically should give up on IE7, people still use it and if your demographic uses the site in IE7 then you should make it work in IE7. There is no point in cutting off a complete group of people because their browser of choice is hideous. They don't know any better!

Answer (score 2):

There is no point in a:visited for main-menu. what if the user visited more than one item in the menu? you want to paint it as visited? it's a menu, not a normal link.

But, if you still want this behaviour then:

In the oneColFixCtrHdr.css you declared:

```
A:visited {
    BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(https://trigger.lwcdirect.com/LWC_00486/uploadImages/2012sbc/darkredbar.jpg)
}
```

You should scope it like this:

```
.oneColFixCtrHdr #stripes UL A:visited { 
        BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(https://trigger.lwcdirect.com/LWC_00486/uploadImages/2012sbc/darkredbar.jpg)
    }
```

In order to apply it on your main-menu.

Comment: It's set up as .oneColFixCtrHdr #stripes ul a:hover,a:active
{
background-image:url(https://trigger.lwcdirect.com/LWC_00486/uploadImages/2012sbc/darkredbar.jpg);
}

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter. anyway, does that not work set up like that? It's also carrying over the formatting for the text, but only once it's clicked.

Comment: I changed it to:
.oneColFixCtrHdr #stripes ul a:visited,a:hover,a:active
{
background-image:url(https://trigger.lwcdirect.com/LWC_00486/uploadImages/2012sbc/darkredbar.jpg);
}

Comment: It kind of fixed it, how can I make it not hover/visited with the background image of the navigation bar though?

Comment: I think you should omit: ".oneColFixCtrHdr" from your css selector

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.roundside a {color:#990000; font-weight:bold}
.roundside a:visited,
.roundside a:hover,
.roundside a:active{ color: #F00; font-weight:normal; }
```

Hope that help you :)

Comment: It removes my bullet points and I still end up with the background image on hover. But thanks!